# What is the name of this technique?

Tags: linux, malware, binary

A while back, on a `Linux` system, I found a strange binary being executed at seemingly random times with some strange arguments, briefly appearing in `ps`. There was nothing to be found at the usual suspect like `init.d`, `.bashrc` and `crontab`. I found where the binary was located, renamed it, and put a script it its place. The script displayed and passed through all the received arguments and recorded the time and the duration of the binary execution, as well as some `/proc` information. I was able to figure out what called it, when, and what were the arguments. What is the name of this `honeypotting`, `MITM` technique?

Comment: Are you able to share the binary

Comment: Logging the occurrences of the bit happening in a way you cannot understand is called using brains :D

Comment: In TDD, people tend to call components like this a Spy. I think in this context you're pretty right when you name it honeypotting or MITM.